# HttpRequest different timeouts per flow

Tags: timeout, httprequest, node-red

i am trying to make two http requests with different timeouts per flow, i know i can configure globally httpRequestTimeout in the settings.js file but it sets the timeouts for all the flows.

I have two flows running in the same node-red and i need to set different timeouts for different http requests, i couldn't find a way to achieve it. I tried set the `msg.req.timeout` and `msg.req.socket.server.timeout` with no sucess.

Is there any way to acess the variables that are defined on settings.js? Mapping it to a env variable would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this can only be set globally in `settings.js` and not over-ridden on a node by node basis.

You can set variables in `settings.js` from environment variables since the file is effectively executed at startup so.

```
...
httpRequestTimeout: process.env.HTTPREQUESTTIMEOUT,
...
```

This would set the timeout to the value of the HTTPREQUESTTIMEOUT environment variable.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem but i will mark this as accepted by your effort. I don't know why this node has that limitation, maybe in the future i will modify it and make a pull request. Thanks for the info.